# How to open posts of certain category and pass its name in the url?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i have displayed all my categories on a page through loop and whenever i click on any category its id is passed and posts related to that category are displayed .but its also shows the id of that category in the url . what i want is to do something in which url shows the name of the particular category that i have clicked . for this i have tried passing name of the category in the link then the id it solves the problem of the url i.e: category name shows up in the url but it creates another problem that it does not open the posts of that category but show error page not found :
my code for displaying all categories is this:

```
<?php
foreach ( $categories as $cat ) {
    $id = $cat->term_id;
    //$name = $cat->cat_name;



    echo '<a href="'.get_site_url() . '/state_league_archives?id='.$id.'">'.$cat->cat_name.'</a>';

 ?>
 <hr>

                        <?php 
}


    ?>
```

and this id i get on the archive page to show its posts like this:

```
     <?php
$cat_id= $_GET['id'];

        $args = array('showposts'=>25, 'category' => '$cat_id' ,'post_type'=>'stateleague-pos-type','category__in'=>array($cat_id));
$query = new WP_Query($args);
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <h1><a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?> |
         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    Read more
                                </a>
         <div class="row">
                            <div class="ct-divider"> </div>
                        </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: you replace the   echo '<a href="'.get_site_url() . '/state_league_archives?id='.echo $id.'">'.$cat->cat_name.'</a>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go to settings->permalinks and select post name in common settings. This should solve your problem.

Also change link to:

```
echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($cat).'">'.$cat->name.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line to:

```
echo '<a href="'. get_category_link( $id ) . '">'.$cat->cat_name.'</a>';
```

Comment: it fullfills my one requirement not the other.
it passes the name of category in the url but it does not open posts of that category instead gives error of :

Nothing Found

It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for. Perhaps searching can help.

Comment: is there any possible way not to change this line and also pass category id to the next page?

Comment: Try changing Permalinks to plain and then revert - this will clear cache. Since then you should not have Not found.

Comment: actually it is not passing the id to the next page i.:e: state_league_archives.php